# How to format number adding points between each 3 numbers

Tags: c

I'm unable to create a function that formate numbers like that :

```
1000 -> 1.000
1000000-> 1.000.0000
99999-> 99.999
```

is there any function in C for that? if it doesn't exist, can you give me an idea about how to it manually?
Thank you,

Comment: transform to string -> iterate backwards -> print up to three characters -> you can work out the rest :)

Comment: ..and what exactly have you tried so far? Have you searched for any functions existing or have you tried to implement something?

Comment: @OMGtechy that's what i'm trying to do, but have some problems i'm trying to solve... Peter Varo  , found a function to print ',' but I need '.', tried successive division but it was a stupid idea, and i'm still trying to fix the function that OMGtechy described

Comment: @saywow think about how you'd do it as a human, write it out, then turn that into pseudo code

Comment: "that's what i'm trying to do,"  --> better to post that code to clearly see the issues that simply  describe the code.

Comment: yeah you're right i'm sorry ^^' anyway I've resolved the problem, but still can't post it since I can't answer my own question (yet), I'll post it asap